# What are the real benefits of upgrading to ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: upgrade, 13.04

What are the real benefits of upgrading to Ubuntu 13.04? please don't consider applications that currently you can get using different sources...

Is more faster? use less memory? optimized for?

Currently I am using 12.04.

Thanks in advance!
Ignacio.-

Comment: Check the release notes: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes ;)

Comment: cool factor ofc.

Comment: Relevant: [OMGUbuntu: Should I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04?](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/should-i-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is graphically smoother, and everything looks nicer. Imo just how much faster everything is makes it worth updating.

Comment: you are right! is more faster!

Answer (score 0):

faster, lighter weight, and lots of bug fixes, but only supported for 9 months, while 12.04 is supported for 5 years
If you do upgrade, there are issues with HDMI audio and Nvidia drivers, to work around this use the [mainline kernel](https://github.com/GM-Script-Writer-62850/Ubuntu-Mainline-Kernel-Updater) (3.8.9 or 3.9rc8)

Answer (score 0):

Dash, HUD, Lenses, Launcher is bloody faster.

I read somewhere ( OMG!Ubuntu maybe) that Unity is now tested on a smartphone.
That smartphone is taken as a reference to tackle performance issues.